# Generating incorrect Fibonacci sequences in C

Tags: c, loops, fibonacci

I'm trying to learn C and I am struggling to see where the error is in this simple program:

```
// variable length arrays.

#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int i, numFibs;

    printf ("How many Fibonacci numbers do you want (between 1 and 75)? ");
    scanf ("%i", &numFibs);

    if (numFibs < 1 || numFibs > 75) {
        printf ("Bad number, sorry!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    unsigned long long int Fibonacci[numFibs];

    Fibonacci[0] = 0;
    Fibonacci[1] = 1;

    for (i = 2; i < numFibs; ++i)
        Fibonacci[i] = Fibonacci[i-2] + Fibonacci[i-1];

    for (i = 0; i < numFibs; ++i)
        printf ("%i    %llu\n", i, Fibonacci[i]);

    printf ("\n");

    return 0;

}
```

This program is from the textbook 'Programming in C'.

Why is it producing a bad sequence:

```
How many Fibonacci numbers do you want (between 1 and 75)? 70
```

// removed some.

```
31    1346269
32    2178309
33    3524578
34    5702887
35    9227465
36    14930352
37    24157817
38    39088169
39    63245986
40    102334155
41    165580141
42    267914296
43    433494437
44    701408733
45    1134903170
46    1836311903
47    2971215073
48    512559680
49    3483774753
50    3996334433
51    3185141890
52    2886509027
53    1776683621
```

It begins to go wrong. 48 should be 4807526976, according to http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibtable.html.

I think it may be overflowing? But the book does not warn about that. Hmm...

Comment: I guess the value is getting truncated because it's getting out of range of `long long int`

Comment: Guess it's just an overflow. Could you let me know what's the value of `sizeof(unsigned long long)` on the platform? Simply something like `printf("%d", sizeof(unsigned long long));` would do.

Comment: you can add a line in the code checking for overflow if Fibonacci[i]<Fibonacci[i-1] then you can print some error message saying its data type overflow.

Comment: I had this exact issue with clang++. ha It went wrong at 48 just like U. Thankful for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason:** It overflows.

Notice that `4807526976 - 512559680 = 4294967296 = 2^32`, it's believed on your platform the type `unsigned long long` is 32 bit instead of 64 bit.

**Solution:** try using larger integer types like `int64_t` (you may need to include `stdint.h`) or maintain your own high precision data type.

For more info on integer overflows, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow